# Jupyter Notebook: command for save the current notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I can automatically save the notebook into HTML after running code. However, sometimes the results are generated too quick, so the output HTML does not have the output in the last cells.

I'm wondering, if it is possible to tell the file to save itself?

Something like

```
# In last cell
current_filename = 'my_file.ipynb'
save_current_notebook(current_filename)
output_HTML(current_filename)
```

Now I can get away with:

```
display(Javascript("IPython.notebook.save_notebook()"),            
        include=['application/javascript'])
```

Answer (score 14):

When the following cell is run, it automatically saves the notebook.

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.save_notebook()
```

I put it as the last cell of the notebook I want to be saved as soon as its execution is completed.

The suggestion made by OP didn't work for me, but the above did. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: After running this in a cell, my notebook keeps saving every 1 second.... How do I stop this? And, which version for ipython and jupyter does this work properly?

Comment: I tested it working on jupyter notebook 5.7.0, Python 3.6.6, IPython 6.5.0. It just saves it once on this setup.

Comment: How to save a notebook with R kernel?

Comment: this is nice, but is there a way to "Save As"

Comment: It seems like it does not save the notebook in its current state. It misses all changes in the last ~5-30 secs.

Comment: @PatrickC., if that is the case you might want to open an issue [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook).

Comment: ReferenceError: IPython is not defined

Comment: @JokeHuang, this thread is about Jupyter Notebook. Most likely you tried to use that in Jupyter Lab, which I don't think supports that.